# How to get a set of all buildings of an OpenStreetMap section in form of single points / Multiple polygons as one point

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, centroids

The objective is to get a set of all buildings of an OpenStreetMap section in form of single points in a shapefile.

1. I downloaded the [section](http://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=13/15.8460/-61.5870) from OSM.
2. Imported the section into QGIS (and later imported it into a PostGIS db using osm2pgsql)
3. To transform the polygons (representing buildings) into points I used the Polygon Centroids function

Unfortunately some of the buildings are represented by multiple polygons subsequently I did get multiple points for one building which I is not what I wanted.

Searching the web I found out that these polygons should be multipolygons but neither QGIS nor osm2pgsql does import these relations so that I could merge the polygons of a building

Any ideas how I could get single point list of the buildings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a very small buffer around your polygons and dissolve all, before creating the centroids.

This would also unite buildings that share a common wall.

Comment: In qgis >buffer with small distance and option "dissolve buffer results" left me with a shapefile of one element which isn't what I was looking for...

Comment: GRASS did do it: v.dissolve input=build output=test column=building

Comment: In QGIS, you can try `Multipart to single part` before creating the centroids.

Answer (score 0):

Used the OSM Download Plugin

Used your coordinates

downloaded the .osm

Loaded this in to QGIS

Extracted 'Building = Yes'

Used the Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygon Centroids

You can delete unwanted centroids or clean up the data before creating the centroids all data has attribution.

[image]

Comment: That is exactly the way I did it, but as I want to use this procedure later for other data I can't manually clean up before or after creating the centroids (too many buildings).